# Selenium and python3 activate textbox without entering a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Writing a script with selenium and python3, is there a possibility to have the script click on a textbox on the http://digesto.asamblea.gob.ni/consultas/coleccion/ (click on "Búsqueda avanzada") without entering a value, so that the cursor is active in that textbox (indicated normally by a blinking vertical line), see example picture?

[image]

Usually one would use

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="txtCaptcha"]').click()`

but this does not give the desired outcome as the textbox is not "active" looking like this:

[image]

My idea is to have the script "activate" the textbox and wait for me to insert a captcha, so that I simply can start writing instead of click in the textbox each time myself.

Comment: What is current output? Share HTML and your current selector

Comment: Hi, Andersson, please, see the update of my original post.

Comment: I see no textarea/input element on that page. Share the code you used to open the page with search field

Comment: I updated the text just before you wrote that comment, you need to click on "Búsqueda avanzada" to see what I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wait for element to be clickable and then click it:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'txtCaptcha'))).click()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not "activate" the textbox for me. Maybe the xpath I send to you is wrong?

Comment: @TilHund , for me it puts the focus into search box once the checkbox `"Búsqueda avanzada"` is selected (try `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'cavanzada'))).click()`)... What is your current output? Did you get an Exception?

Comment: Fixed my issue. It was on me. I works well now. Thank you again, Anderson! :)